# Mouse detected as keyboard

Tags: mouse, xinput

I have tried to use my mouse (perixx mx-2000) on Fedora 18 and Crunchbang 11, and for both of them, the mouse does not work.

The "funny" thing is that the mouse seems to be detected as a keyboard:

```
$ xinput
Holtek USB Gaming Mouse    id=15 [slave keyboard (3)]
```

I would like to know if there is a way to correct that kind of bug. If there is not, does can an adapter usb/mouse do the trick?

Comment: I'd expect a "multi-button mouse" to be detected as a keyboard of sorts. My Kensington presenter (laser pointer, forward/backward/home buttons) is considered such. Perhaps the mouse is gone? What does the "does not work" mean here?

Comment: You would find an answer if you google the xinput output message appropriately (taking out the values that are system dependent: `Holtex USB Gaming Mouse keyboard` http://aptosid.com/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=2454

Answer (score 2):

It's a known problem with `Holtek` gaming mice (should be fixed for those running `kernel 3.11.2` or later, see [commit](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=d4f5189052c68f5bae3aac62b357577ecb862fee)). If you're using an older kernel, there's workaround (recompile the kernel) described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232564/sharkoon-drakonia-gaming-mouse-doesnt-work-at-all).